# Como hacer scroll infinito

Tags: javascript, php, html

Llevo más de un mes tratando de hacer un scroll infinito para mi página y me es imposible. He probado de todo, he buscado videos de YouTube, enlaces de Google, cogido código de otras personas, preguntado en foros y nada. Me han dado algunas soluciones, pero no consigo hacerlas. He conseguido hacer una función *AJAX* que se active cuando deslices e inserte el código en un `<div>`.

Pero, solo lo hace una vez. Luego, como el `<div>` ya tiene texto, no funciona más.

Tan solo quiero un scroll infinito que cargue unas publicaciones cuando deslices. Nada más. Muchas gracias.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
 <script>
        function ajax(){
        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = 'http://localhost/Registro/articulo.php';
        http.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
              console.log(this.responseText);
              document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = this.responseText;
              
            }
        }
        
        http.open("GET", url);
        http.send();
          
    }
    


    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count=0;

        $(document).scroll(function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$(document).height())
            {
            count+=1;
                $("body").append( "<article>",ajax(),"</article><article>",ajax(),"</article><article>",ajax(),"</article>");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Y este es el codigo que quiero cargar. El de articulo.php:

```
<?php include("includes/header3.php")?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos4.css">
<div class= "articulo" id="articulo"> 
    <article>
     <?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
         $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
           $publicacion=$mostrar['publicacion'];
           ?>
           <?php } ?>
       <hgroup>
           <div id="user" onclick="location.href='Perfil.php'"><img src="Imagenes/Foto de perfil - copia.png" id="fotouser">
             <h1 id="nombreuser">
           <?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones WHERE publicacion= '".$publicacion."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
         $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
           $autor= ucfirst($mostrar['nombre']);?> 
         <?php echo $autor ?> 
         <?php } ?>
         </h1></button>
         </div>
         <h1 id="Tituloarticulo">Título del primer artículo</h1>
       </hgroup>
         <time datetime="08-02-2021"> Publicado el 08-02-2021</time>
         <table>
         <?php
         $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
           ?>
         <tr>
           <td><?php echo $mostrar['publicacion'] ?> </td>
         </tr> 
         <?php 
         }
         ?>
         </table>
         <footer> 
             <p>Comentarios (0)</p>
             <button id="Comentarios"></button>
         </footer>
     </article>
     </div>
```

Comment: Aqui lo explican bien: https://youtu.be/XEf5jW9Y9oE

Comment: Esta pregunta se ha hecho cientos  de veces en la comunidad en inglés, por no decir que miles de veces, te dejo este enlace donde puedes consultar un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764723/how-to-do-infinite-scroll-with-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores en este código:

1. ¿Por qué combinas jQuery con Javascript puro? Lo mejor es que te definas por alguno y no mezclar; de esta forma tu código es más claro y evitas confusiones. Las peticiones AJAX con jQuery o [Javascript puro](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) son mucho más sencillas.
2. En cada nueva llamada remplazas el contenido de `response` en lugar de agregarlo, en lugar de `=`, usa `+=` para agregar.
3. La petición AJAX actualiza directamente el contenedor y no devuelve contenido, de hecho, tampoco intentes que lo devuelva, porque se trata de una promesa y se resuelve en momentos diferentes.

```
function ajax(){
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'http://localhost/Registro/articulo.php';
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
            // Usa += para agregar en lugar de remplazar
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML += this.responseText;
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", url);
    http.send();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=0;

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$(document).height())
        {
            count+=1;
            // Solo ejecuta la función, ahí se actualiza el contenedor
            ajax();
        }
    });
});
```

Ahora, el otro problema que enfrentas es que siempre te va a devolver el mismo contenido, porque no estás enviando parámetros a PHP para saber lo que ya recibiste; supongo que eso será tema de otra pregunta.

Comment: Solo decirte que muchísimas gracias. Me ha servido mucho. Espero que Dios te lo pague. Gracias.